# How to retrive information from another website to my website in classic asp

Tags: string, asp-classic

I want to retrive Product Status from other website to my website. For that I am using this code.

```
Dim xml
set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xml.Open "GET", "http://www.midwayusa.com/Product/"&sCode  , false
xml.Send

Dim strRetrive,strtCnt,endCnt,strStatus,strShippingMessage,a
strRetrive=xml.responseText
strtCnt=InStr(strRetrive,"productStatus")
strtCnt=Instr(strtCnt,strRetrive,">")
endCnt=Instr(strtCnt,strRetrive,"<")
strStatus = (mid(strRetrive,(strtCnt+1),(endCnt-(strtCnt+1))))
getStatusFromMidway = trim(a)
```

This gives me status but lots of spaces and unwanted characters. I tried trim function, but that is not removing spaces at all. Afterwards, I tried Replace(vari," ",""), but it removes all spaces from string which is not good..

Now, I am thinking to use XML DOM, or similar functionality, Can anyone help me for that?

Comment: Trim will only remove leading and trailing spaces. You may need to write a function that strips the characters you don't want. What type of value should productStatus contain? Just text, numbers only, text and numbers, any other characters?

Comment: I know, it removes only leading and trailing spaces, but in my case its not removing those spaces...

Comment: Are you sure they're spaces? There are lots of white space charachters, try replacing vbcr, vblf, vbcrlf and vbTab (Chr(13), Chr(10), Chr(13) & Chr(10), Chr(9))

Comment: I am not sure, but if I use Replace(str," ",""), then it removes all spaces including spaces between two words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your Trim with this function (SuperTrim) that removes all leading and trailing non-word characters.

eg. Add this function and change **getStatusFromMidway = trim(a)** to **getStatusFromMidway = SuperTrim(a)**

```
Function SuperTrim(input)
    Dim regex, result
    Set regex = New RegExp
    regex.Pattern = "^\W+"
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Global = True
    result = regex.Replace(input, "")
    regex.Pattern = "\W+$"
    result = regex.Replace(result, "")
    Set regex = nothing
    SuperTrim = result
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you tell me what this function 'll do?

Comment: Hey, its working like charm... Can you elaborate your answer please? Because, I don't want only solution, I want to understand code... Thanks

Comment: It uses regular expressions to remove leading and trailing non-word characters. ^\W+ takes care of the leading and \W+$ takes care of trailing. Non-word characters are everything but A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _ (underscore). If there are any other characters that you might want to allow then you will need to change the \W to a different pattern.

Comment: Thanks... But can you tell me, how non-word characters come from? I mean, If Replace(strng," ","") works fine than what it's mean? Isn't it replacing white spaces?

And how this function is not removing spaces between two words?

Anyways, thanks for great function...

Comment: In the regular expression pattern ^ means at the start and $ means before the end. That's why they don't pick up spaces in between word characters. This is working for you because your string must contain some unprintable characters like carriage returns, tabs, line spaces etc. I can't see how Replace(strng," ","") would have been working (aside from the inner spaces) for you.